# CSS Grid Dynamically assign grid column or grid-template-columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to be able to dynamically assign the numbers of columns an item would take up in a grid row.

In flex I could just do something like give it a name like `.col-sm-25` (imaginative, I know) and give it a styling of `flex-basis: 25%`. However, flex doesn't have the grid-gap property so I'm trying to see if there's a way to do this in css grid.

As it's dynamically created by the editor in our CMS system and they can't choose the container to add items into, `grid-template-columns` can only really be `repeat(12, 1fr)` or something to that effect.

Is there a way I can say for item `.col-sm-25` to take up the next 4 available column in the grid row? I don't know what order the items will come in so can't say what `grid-column-start` would be.

I know it [can be done](https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/wzNOxr) in flebox but it just feels so hacky

Comment: Note that the `gap` property, designed for multiple box models, will be taking over for `grid-gap`. It's already available for flexbox in Firefox. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#gap-shorthand

Comment: Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can say for item .col-sm-25 to take up the next 4 available column in the grid row?

## Yes.

Just define the `grid-column-end` as `span 4`

[**Grid-column-end @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end)

> **span n**
>
> Contributes a grid span to the grid item’s placement such that the **column end edge of the grid item’s grid area is n lines from the start edge**.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  background: green;
}

.span-3 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  background: lightblue;
}

.span-4 {
  grid-column-end: span 4;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box span-4"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box span-4"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box span-2"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box span-3"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box span-4"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Note, as is shown this can lead to "breakage" of the grid where there are less than 4 columns *left* in the row.

However, css-grid can *back-fill* using `grid-auto-flow:dense;`